# How to refresh a LINQ to Entities Query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have the following LINQ to Entities code:

```
var vans = from v in objDB.vans.Include("van_assignments.pickup_requests.to_location")
                               .Include("van_assignments.pickup_requests.from_location")
                               .Include("van_assignments.pickup_requests.person")
                               .Include("school")
           select v;


gcVans.DataSource = vans;
```

Now, in another method (ie a refresh button), I am needing to refresh that query as changes were made to the remote DB.

I tried calling the above code again, but it doesn't refresh the data. Does anyone know of a best practice for forcing LINQ to Entities to refresh from the remote database?

**Edit**: After a bit of dabbling, this causes the van information to update. However, all the foreign key data that was loaded with the .include() function does not update. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
var vans = from v in objDB.vans.Include("van_assignments.pickup_requests.to_location")
                   .Include("van_assignments.pickup_requests.from_location")
                   .Include("van_assignments.pickup_requests.person")
                   .Include("school")
           select v;

objDB.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, vans);

gcVans.RefreshDataSource();
```

Comment: It is not refreshed with that code. Also, I updated the issue with some new information. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you remove the "from v in " and "select v" parts, does it do anything different at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the wrong [MergeOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx).

The default value, `AppendOnly`, tries to preserve client-side changes and doesn't overwrite on a refresh. Perhaps you want `OverwriteChanges`? Then you would not need to call `Refresh`.

To set this, you'd do something like:

```
(vans as ObjectQuery).MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

Comment: Thank you, can you provide an example of how I would use the merge option?

Comment: I added an example. Do that before enumerating the results.

Comment: Adding that will cause LINQ to Entities to refresh from the server when I call, objDB.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, vans); ? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: No, adding that will cause the query to return fresh objects instead of fixing up results to the values already in memory.